# Modifying slices of DataFrames: What to use instead of .ix in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was iterating through a DataFrame in Pandas when my app crashed. I had to do some cleaning of the data starting from the last index that was operated on. I ended up using this code:

```
df.ix[start_index:,["col"]] = ""
```

Shortly after I got a deprecation warning. However I spent quite a bit of time searching for which functions I could use to achieve that end result and `.ix` was the only thing I found.

In the future, how will I achieve something like this?

Comment: `data.loc[start_index:, ["col"]] = ""` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions - with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for replace by positions and also position by columns name by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
df.iloc[start_index:,[df.columns.get_loc("col")]] = ""
```

Or you can select by labels with indexing index values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.index[start_index]:,["col"]] = ""
```